# Ajax call in p:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

Hi guys is there a way to fire an ajax call in a p:selectManyCheckbox of primefaces once I check one of them? something like this:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox  label="Elements" value="#{crearVacacionMB.elementSelected}" layout="grid" columns="1">
    <f:selectItems  value="#{MB.elements}" />
    <p:ajax event="check" listener="#{MB.function}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

And my MB:

```
public void function(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    System.out.println("I was fired");

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060246/jsf-2-selectmanycheckbox-how-can-i-get-the-clicked-item-in-the-ajax-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060246/jsf-2-selectmanycheckbox-how-can-i-get-the-clicked-item-in-the-ajax-method

Answer (score 6):

The code you posted produces a JSF error, at least with Mojarra 2.2, and I am surprised you haven't mentioned it:

```
<p:ajax> Event:check is not supported.
```

Remove the `event` attribute from `<p:ajax>`: the ajax behaviour will default to the default event `valueChange`:

```
<p:ajax listener="#{MB.function}"/>
```

**Links**:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)