# How to get selected items from p:selectManyCheckbox?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a selectManyCheckbox which have a list of items shown, When ever I select an item I want a callback on my backing bean to be triggered and then get the value of the selected item for doing some filtering with this value. My problem is that I can't get the backing bean method to be executed. Have tried several ways, here's my code

## 1

```
<h:form class="block filter image-list-filter">
   <div class="title-block"> FILTER </div>
       <div class="content">
           <ul class="filter-block">
               <p:selectManyCheckbox id="vals" layout="grid" 
                   valueChangeListener="#{bean.selectFilter}" onchange="submit();">
                  <p:ajax event="click" process="@form" update="@all"/>
                  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" var="filter" 
                        itemValue="#{filter.idFilter}" itemLabel="#{filter.descr}" 
                        itemDescription="#{filter.image}"/>
               </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            </ul>
        </div>
</h:form>
```

## 2

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="vals" layout="grid">
     <p:ajax event="click" process="@form" update="@all" 
           listener="#{bean.selectFilter}" />
     <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" var="filter" 
         itemValue="#{filter.idFilter}" itemLabel="#{filter.descr}" 
         itemDescription="#{filter.image}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

## 3

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="vals" layout="grid" 
      valueChangeListener="#{bean.selectFilter}">
      <p:ajax event="click" process="@form" update="@all"/>
      <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" var="filter" 
          itemValue="#{filter.idFilter}" itemLabel="#{filter.descr}" 
               itemDescription="#{filter.image}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

## Backing Bean Method

```
public void selectFilter(ValueChangeEvent dege) {
   Object[] selFilters = (Object[]) dege.getNewValue();
   if (selFilters.length != 0) {
       //Do stuff
   }
}
```

The options attribute is an ArrayList of a particular object that stores the available values. Of course, this attribute has setter & getter. PF version is 5.0

Comment: You may need to use a converter. Take a look in this question from BalusC, it should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060246/jsf-2-selectmanycheckbox-how-can-i-get-the-clicked-item-in-the-ajax-method

Comment: @Pellizon Have tryed to use converter with no success. When selecting an item no method is called =(

Comment: What is your PF version? I know that there is some bugs on valueChangeListener for old versions. Also, Remove that onchange=submit(), it may break your ajax request

Comment: @Pellizon my Pf version is 5.0 Already tried removing the submit, but still nothing

Comment: What about `<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.methodXpto}"/>`. And in your bean, `public void methodXpto()`. Check if it will be triggered. Note that you don't need to pass any argument to the function, just call it. Let me know if it works (Remove the ValueChangeListener of your p:selectManyCheckbox )

Comment: @Pellizon still, no luck

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things in your code that is done much differently than I would have done it, and this makes it difficult for me to determine exactly what is causing the problem. Instead, I will explain how I would have solved it:

Component:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="vals" layout="grid" value="#{bean.selectedValue}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.selectFilter}" update="@all"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" var="filter" 
            itemValue="#{filter.idFilter}" itemLabel="#{filter.descr}" 
            itemDescription="#{filter.image}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Bean:

```
private Object[] selectedValue;
public Object[] getSelectedValue(){
    return selectedValue;
}

public void setSelectedValue(Object[] newValue){
    selectedValue = newValue;
}

public void selectFilter(){
    Object[] selFilters = getSelectedValue();
    if (selFilters.length != 0) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

As far as I know this is the standard way of doing things, submitting the values through the normal property setter and then interacting with it in a triggered method like selectFilter. I would also discourage the usage of `update="@all"` as this will refresh the entire page. Updating only the parts of the page that actually changes with something like `update="@(.image-list)"` will tend to give a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

For getting selected items use h:form tags!

Comment: This answer could be made more valuable by showing how it would work in the context of the question or adding an explanation as to why it is the correct solution.